# Ventanas emergentes WPF y C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Buen día comunidad,

Tengo una duda, desde C# con WPF es posible mostrar mensajes a los usuarios que esten usando la aplicación, es decir mandar un mensaje diciendo "Favor salir del sistema" y se muestre a los usuarios, independiente del menu que tengan en ejecución.

PD: Se como mostrar mensajes segun x acción, busque mucha documentación pero no encuentro nada que me pueda ayudar.

Muchas gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: A qué te refieres con "ventanas emergentes?. Si te refieres a una ventana normal, puedes crearla y mandarla mostrar, o usar MessageBox.Show. Si te refieres a notificaciones con popups, lo mejor es utilizar alguna librería de terceros.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la `clase` `MessageBox`, aqui un ejemplo:

```
        MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Mensaje de Alerta","Titulo de Alerta", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
```

La variable `result` obtiene el valor de la acción que tome el usuario en el `messageBox`, estas acciones estan definidas por el `Enum` `MessageBoxButton`, que para este ejemplo solo muestra `Ok` y `Cancel`.

Saludos, espero te sirva